Is there an option for setting undo files' extension, similar to the one for backups?
For backup files, there's the option backupext for changing the extension of backups from filename.ext~ to (for example) filename.ext.bak by using
set backupext=.bak

in a vimrc file. Is there a similar setting to give undo files a different extension?

No, there's no such option. Vim will pick the name for the undo file.
While the existence of the backupdir and undodir options suggest an analogy, it breaks down when it comes to the extension.
Quoting from :help undo-persistance:

Vim saves undo trees in a separate undo file, one for each edited file, using
a simple scheme that maps filesystem paths directly to undo files.

It also says

You can use the undofile() function to find out the file name that Vim would
use.

To show the undo file name for your current file, you could do
:echo undofile(expand('%'))

And that's that.
To keep undo files (and backup files, too) from getting into your way, you can set undodir as mentioned above. You can have Vim write its undo files to a permanent directory apart from your project files.
Personally, I have a directory ~/.vim/tmp/undo to keep them.

There is 'undodir', though.
